# Is it safe to check-in a RSA private key?

Tags: rsa, source-code, credentials

As far as I know, it is bad to check-in something like a password in a version control system. However, I saw in a project that a `private_key.pem` file with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- ...` content is checked in. For me this smells like a security issue.

Is it a security issue?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it a security issue?

It depends on the impact of a key compromise and the probability of the compromise.

- If this is only some unimportant key (like only used for testing), then this is not a problem.
- If this is a private repository only accessible to the few trusted users which also need access to the key, then this usually not a problem. Note that a repository in the cloud hosted by some service provider might not fit *"only accessible to the few trusted users which also need access to the key"* since also the service provider can access it. And note that the probability of a key compromise increases with the number of users which have access to the key.
- If this is a sensitive key in a public repository, then this is definitely a problem.

Comment: But would this points not also apply for passwords? And who knows if the project will be public some day, without good previous review? I think anything that may become sensitive, should by default not be checked in.

Comment: @fabpico: *" I think anything that may become sensitive, should by default not be checked in"* - which might include in many cases the source code itself. Instead I think it should be made clear how sensitive the data in the repository are, so that sensitive content is not simply made public - at least not w/o deep review and cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Access codes, credentials, crypto keys and everything else may be stored in a source/version control system for management facilitation and lifecycle monitoring reasons. It's not *the stored info* that makes the difference, but *who* has access to it and *why*.

So, if the repo you were looking at (that has the private key) is e.g. one that stores ansible playbooks or kubernetes tls secrets, then it should be expected to find keys in it. It's also expected that access to that repo should only be granted to people whose job is to work with these things (e.g. infrastructure).

If, on the other hand, the repo stores e.g. your code base, to which access is granted to several software developers, then the key should not be there.

> Is it a security issue?

Yes, if unauthorized people have access to it. No, otherwise*.

---

*Insider threats (e.g. authorized personnel abusing their authority or have their credentials stolen) are always a problem - this does not mean that you never store sensitive or critical information to a version control system or never give access to anyone; you have to trust the correct people at some point

Answer (score 0):

It is sometimes necessary to carry **secrets**, that includes passwords and client certificates - think about (unattended) embedded device projects. Although it may be preferable to supply sensitive configuration files separately, for example deploying them using tools like Ansible, or flashing NVRAM etc.

That can be done at the time of **provisioning the device** and possibly **customized per device**, whereas the project code is otherwise standard and identical on all devices.

So, this is not necessarily a big issue, as long as the repo remains "private". What is important here is that the private key may not be reused for another purpose, like logging in to your corporate infrastructure via SSH.

Also, it may be good to have one private key per client, so that if a key is compromised it can be **revoked** without affected the other enrolled clients. Takes a bit more effort and organization but easily automated.